# Кто такой вертопрах?

Tags: этимология

Интересно, откуда пошло слово "вертопрах"? По моим соображениям, изначально это расхититель могил (вертит прах). Правильно?

Comment: Может оно созвучно глаголу порхать? Представляю воробьев или других птиц, которые перелетают по верхушкам кустов, деревьев, не сеют и не пашут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Ни к каким расхитителям гробниц вертопрахи не относились. Слово *вертопрах* (женск. *вертопрашка*), как показывает морфологический состав, образовалось из сложения основ: отглагольной **верт** и именной **прах**. Церковнославянизм *прах* здесь выступает в значении "пыль". Это до некоторой степени устанавливает предел, после которого не могло появиться слово "вертопрах". Слово прах перестает употребляться в значении "пыль" даже в высоком стиле с конца XVIII в. Итак, с полной вероятностью можно думать, что возникновение слова вертопрах датируется временем не позднее первой половины XVIII в. Действительно, в языке петровского времени слово вертопрах уже было употребительно. Так, оно встречается в автобиографичекой повести подьячего Семена Петровича Левицкого, датируемой приблизительно 1710—1720 гг. Вертопрах в ту эпоху означало `ветреный щеголь'. См. у М. В. Ломоносова в стихотворении "Златой младых людей и беспечальный век":

Но есть ли б чистой был Дияне мил твой взгляд

И был бы, Балабан, ты сверх того женат,

То б ты на пудре спал и ел всегда помаду,

На беса б был похож и с переду и с заду.

Тогда б перед тобой и самой **вертопрах**

Как важной был Катон у всякого в глазах.

В "Словаре Академии Российской" слова *вертопрах, вертопрашка* уже рассматриваются как "простонародные уничижительные". Вертопрах определяется так: "Непостоянник, ветреник, человек в поступках, поведении и в речах своих весьма неосновательный, легкомысленный" . Это определение словарем 1847 г. сжимается до такой формулы: "Легкомысленный, неосновательный человек; ветреник". Буквально та же характеристика повторится и в словаре Грота — Шахматова. Даль присоединяет к этой характеристике лишь одно областное слово "легостай". В словаре Ушакова слово "вертопрах" рассматривается с точки зрения современного литературного употребления как живое, разговорное. Его значение определяется так же, как и во всех предшествующих словарях: "Легкомысленный, ветреный человек". Конечно, степень употребительности этого слова, его экспрессивная яркость и круг его стилевых возможностей были очень различны в разные периоды истории русского литературного языка XVIII и XIX в.

(по Виноградову В. В.)

Comment: >Даль присоединяет к этой характеристике лишь одно областное слово "легостай".

Вот слово *"легостай"* для меня более непонятное, чем *"вертопрах"*. Интересно, как оно образовано?

"Лег-" что-то лёгкое? А что тогда "-стай"? Или "-остай"?

Answer (score 3):

Прах - *порох, пыль*. Вертопрах может быть поэтическим синонимом/эпитетом ветра, ведь тот только и делает, что пыль гоняет? Ветреный человек = вертопрах.

Смотрим САР 1789-1794 :

> Вертопрахъ, вертопрашка, уничиж.
> Непостоянникъ, ветреникъ, легкомысленный человек...

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Желая проверить, как поэты используют перекличку *ветер -- вертопрах*, я нашел  много стихов и выбрал вот эти, пародийные :

Виктор Завадский

**Слова на ветер...**

И что-то с ветром нас роднит двоих...
(Валентин Проталин)

> Любителям друг друга и природы,
>
> Как нам весной гулялось, молодым!
>
> Мы не боялись ветреной погоды —
>
> Ведь ветер нам обоим был родным.
>
> Что по крови, по духу, по идее
>
> Сродни мы ветру, может убедить
>
> И ветреное наше поведенье,
>
> Не надо за примером и ходить:
>
> Когда тебя, тобою увлеченный,
>
> Я встретил носом к носу на траве,
>
> Ты оказалась ветреной девчонкой —
>
> И без царя, но с ветром в голове!
>
> Я вертопрах и сам! Чем мне гордиться! —
>
> Такой же в голове моей сквозняк
>
> И ветер. Но зато и заразиться
>
> Ветрянкой не боюсь, я — сам ветряк!
>
> Да, ветряная мельница. Проверить
>
> Несложно это: я слова мелю
>
> Не просто, а — бросая их на ветер.
>
> Зачем? А населенье веселю!

Comment: >Прах - порох, пыль.

И ещё *порошок* у южных славян. 

Например, стиральный порошок -- *прах за пране*. Порошок для стирки, если дословно.

.

Технический совет. Когда цитируете стихи на этом форуме, то чтобы между строчками не было большого отступа, как у вас выше, можно сделать так. Для перехода на новую строку нажимать не 2 раза "энтер" (тогда получается абзац), а 2 пробела и "энтер".

Answer (score 1):

*"Слово прах перестает употребляться в значении "пыль" даже в высоком стиле с конца XVIII в."*
А как же у Тютчева: *"взметая **прах** летучий"?* (Это из стихотворения "Как весел грохот летних бурь..." 1851 года.)
А происхождение простое: был такой просторечный глагол **"прашить"** (его фиксирует, например, Даль), который означал **"превращать что-либо в прах",** **заниматься мотовством**. В соединении с "вертеть/вращать" (отсюда пре-вращать) получаем именно этот смысл:
вертопрах — тот, кто превращает (достаток) в прах.

Comment: В поддержку Вашего ответа. Толковый словарь Даля (2-е издание). Том 3 (1882): Прашить добро, именье, сорить, мотать. Что было, все испрашилъ. Прашиться, раскольн. предаваться суетнымъ забавамъ, мирщиться, особ. плясать. https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F_(2-%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)._%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC_3_(1882).pdf/402